# OpenOCD select target for flash write_image?

Tags: microcontroller, openocd

I have a JTAG chain of 5 microcontrollers, where each microcontroller has its own ELF image. I understand that I would use `flash write_image` to write the ELF, but I can't seem to figure out which target/flash bank to write it to. Is there a way to select a target for the image to be written to (or am I going down the wrong path)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenOCD has an `active target`, which you can select with the `targets [name]` [command](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/CPU-Configuration.html#CPU-Configuration). Easy to miss this one, as it displays the targets without the `name` parameter.